# The Great Ring in the darkness binds us

Tags: riddle

The Great Ring in the darkness binds us, the Eye of Fire at its centre. If you are on the ball (and I know you are), tell me, how many times have you been here before?

Hint:

> Now, if you asked me, I would answer 42. But what is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The great ring in the darkness could be:

> The path of the earth around the sun (the eye of fire). We are all bound to follow that orbital path by the effect of gravity.

How many times have I been here before?

> Well, that's the number of times that the planet has been at this point in it's orbital path. Which is a personal question as you're asking my age. So I'll just say that it's more than 20 and less than 60!